# What is meant by Interface.class in java?

Tags: java, interface

When it comes to java, Suppose I is an interface, What is meant by I.class? And what is it use for?

Comment: For every class there is an object that allows you to query some of the class's properties, create new instances of the class, et al.  `<ClassName>.class` is the way you obtain a reference to that object.  (And an interface is just a special type of class.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "class" member of an interface is most useful when creating objects via reflection (using a ClassLoader and the class's name) to check for methods and see if a new class isAssignableFrom a given interface.

Answer (score 4):

Every class or interface you write is associated with a `java.lang.Class` object during runtime in Java. All instances of the same class share the same `Class` object and you can obtain the `Class` object by calling the CLassName/InterfaceName.class or obj.getClass() method of the corresponding object. Read the [What is the use of class “java.lang.Class” ?](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/what-is-use-of-class-javalangclass-why.html) article for more details.

Answer (score 2):

It's the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instance for the interface, `I`. With it, you can find the methods and fields of the interface, check to see if objects implement the interface, etc.

`Type.class` is syntactic sugar for obtaining object `Class` object via [`Class.forName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29). Although the "class" might seem out of place when applied to an interface, it works the same way, and provides much of the same information. You won't be able to reflect on any constructors, however.